# Spark - Yarn FetchFailed Exception

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I have a cluster configuration using Yarn with 3 nodes. Each node has:
4 Cores
8 Gb Ram
500 Gb HDD Space
I wanted to run a Spark job on top of it, but it fails with the above exception. When i run a job with a small test file everything goes well, but when i try a 250mb text file i get an exception.

I am using Python with pySpark to run a clustering with KMeans.

Here are my configurations for yarn and spark:

YARN

```
    <property>
            <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
            <value>2048</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
            <value>6144</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
            <value>6144</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
            <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ration</name>
            <value>4</value>
    </property>
```

SPARK

```
spark.master    yarn
spark.yarn.am.memory 1g
spark.yarn.am.cores 2
spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout 30s
spark.executor.cores 1
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead 1g
spark.core.connection.ack.wait.timeout 600s
spark.network.timeout 800s
spark.executor.memory 4g
spark.port.maxRetries 50
```

And the errors i am getting (sorry for long post):

```
2018-06-25 17:23:21 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 1.0 in stage 3.3 (TID 33, worker-02, executor 2): FetchFailed(BlockManagerId(1, worker-03, 45538, None), shuffleId=0, mapId=0, reduceId=1, message=
org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Failed to connect to worker-03/167.99.250.122:45538
at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:519)
at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:450)
at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:61)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.insertAll(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:153)
at org.apache.spark.Aggregator.combineCombinersByKey(Aggregator.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:105)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to worker-03/167.99.250.122:45538
at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:245)
at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:187)
at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService$$anon$2.createAndStart(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:113)
at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.fetchAllOutstanding(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:141)
at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.lambda$initiateRetry$0(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:169)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
... 1 more
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: worker-03/167.99.250.122:45538
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:323)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:633)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
... 11 more

)
```